# Regex: Trying to match a string that contains users names

Tags: regex

I am trying to match user names for accounts.

All out usernames only contain characters. However there are a few that contain "**.**"

I am trying to write a expression that will match all username if they have special characters within them or not but have not go very far.

You can see from below i have 2 entry with 2 different account names. I need an expression that will match both.

So far i have this but keep getting tripped up on the special character.

Account Name:(\s\w*[.\D])

Can anyone help?

```
A security-enabled global group was created. Subject: Security ID: Account Name: testing Account Domain:  Logon ID:

A security-enabled global group was created.Account Name: testing.testing Account Domain:  Logon ID:  New Group: Security ID:  Group Name:  Group Domain:  SAM Account Name: SID History:
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like this [`Account Name:\s*([\w.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/VQmU5K/1)?

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`Account Name:(\s[\w.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/GjSrOY/1)

`[\w.]+` match 1 or more occurrences of `a-zA-Z0-9_` and `.` character

if you need to match any special character then use [`Account Name:(\s[a-zA-Z]+.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/jRv8TJ/1)

`[a-zA-Z]+` match at least 1 or more alphabet, although you can also use range `{}` if you have minimum characters for the username

Comment: that's there to make sure about space and some name characters , although `[a-zA-Z]` would make more sense ,thanks